# Fazer Regex.Split no que não estiver entre "..."

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

Qual expressão regular eu uso para obter o caractere de vírgula que não está dentro dos campos `"..."`, exemplo:

```
line1, "line2", "hello,world", 215, X + Y
     ^        ^              ^    ^
```

Quero obter apenas os indicados, estou usando a expressão **`(?!.*"),`** porém ela não funciona.

Comment: Os que não estiverem entre aspas " "?

Comment: Sim, **quero pegar as vírgulas que não estiverem entre aspas**.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: `(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`

Comment: Isso ai ta pegando os campos `"..."` não as virgulas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O grande problema disso que você quer é que o analisador de expressão regular não sabe o que é uma aspa que abre e uma aspa que fecha. Por exemplo:

```
"line2", "hello,world"
```

`"line2"` seria um grupo, `", "` seria outro e `"hello,world"` seria outro, o que inviabilizaria uma expressão regular que resolve tudo. Ou seja, você precisa contar o grupo todo, com ou sem aspas.

Minha sugestão é você contar as vírgulas juntamente com cada grupo, ou seja:

```
(("[\w\s,]*")(,)?)|([\w\s\+]*(,)?)
```

Que quer dizer:

> Conte tudo o que está dentro de aspas terminado por 0 ou 1 vírgulas, ou o que não tem aspas terminado por 0 ou 1 vírgulas.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Veja aqui funcionando](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TE79lBELkuQuZzAK).

Feito isso, a vírgula sempre estará no segundo grupo e o que deve ser realmente importante para a sua aplicação no primeiro.

Answer (score 3):

Eu monteu uma REGEX diferente da [do @cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113261/fazer-regex-split-no-que-n%C3%A3o-estiver-entre#answer-113275), mas a análise é a mesma:

> Capturar o grupo anterior para identificar a virgula posterior.

REGEX:

```
(?|(['"])[^\1]+?\1(,)?|([^,])(,))
```

[Veja funcionando](https://regex101.com/r/kV4vO1/1).

A virgula também se encontrara sempre no segundo grupo.

Comment: O estranho é que sua expressão funciona em outras plataformas, mas na .NET Framework não é validada: http://prntscr.com/a3lno4